# How to create singleton classes dynamically in python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, singleton, metaprogramming

I want to create classes dynamically such that :
class  is created as per the "name" provided by the user. This class should be singleton.

I want to implement some sort of messaging functionality where the communication channel (topic) with name "name" should be created only once (singleton), and several observers can be attached to that topic.

I tried to do something like below but not sure how to create singleton classes dynamically.

```
class GTopic:
    def register(self, observer):
        pass


class TopicA(GTopic):
    instance = None

    class __TopicA:
        def __init__(self):
            self._observers = []
            self.messages = []

        def register(self, observer):
            if observer not in self._observers:
                self._observers.append(observer)

        def send_message(self, msg):
            for observer in self._observers:
                observer.update(__class__.__name__, id(self), msg)
            self.messages.remove(msg)

        def send(self, msg):
            if not msg:
                return
            self.messages.append(msg)
            self.send_message(msg)

    def __new__(cls):
        if not TopicA.instance:
            TopicA.instance = TopicA.__TopicA()
            print("TopicA not present, creating new")
        print("TopicA already present")
        return TopicA.instance


class TopicB(GTopic):
    instance = None

    class __TopicB:
        def __init__(self):
            self._observers = []
            self.messages = []

        def register(self, observer):
            if observer not in self._observers:
                self._observers.append(observer)

        def send_message(self, msg):
            for observer in self._observers:
                observer.update(__class__.__name__, id(self), msg)
            self.messages.remove(msg)

        def send(self, msg):
            if not msg:
                return
            self.messages.append(msg)
            self.send_message(msg)

    def __new__(cls):
        if not TopicB.instance:
            TopicB.instance = TopicB.__TopicB()
            print("TopicB not present, creating new")
        print("TopicB already present")
        return TopicB.instance

"""
def __new__(cls):
    if not cls.instance:
        cls.instance = cls.cls()
        print(f"{cls} not present, creating new")
    print(f"{cls} already present")
    return cls.instance
"""

class GQueue:

    @staticmethod
    def get_topic(topic):
        if topic == "A":
            return TopicA()
        elif topic == "B":
            return TopicB()
        """
        else:
            Topic = type("Topic{}".format(topic), (TopicA,), {"instance": None, "__new__": __new__})
            return Topic()
        """


class Observer:
    def __init__(self, a=0):
        self.a = a

    def update(self, topic_name, topic_id, msg):
        print(f"Message for observer {id(self)} from {topic_name}: {msg}")
        self.a = 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # client code
    topic_a = GQueue.get_topic("A")
    topic_b = GQueue.get_topic("B")
    obs1 = Observer()
    obs2 = Observer()
    topic_a.register(obs1)
    topic_b.register(obs1)
    topic_a.register(obs2)
    topic_a.send("hello to A")
    topic_b.send("hello to B")

    # Now I want to do something like :

    """
    topic_x = GQueue.get_topic("X")
    topic_x.register(obs1)
    """
```

Above code works fine.
Now I want to do something like :

```
    topic_x = GQueue.get_topic("X")
    topic_x.register(obs1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making this more difficult than is has to be. Why not create multiple instances of a single topic class. And store them in an aggregate class that follows the singleton pattern.
Maybe put the instances in a dict so you can easily retrieve them by a name.

Comment: Yes I agree this could be done. But in fact my intention was to explore the "possibility of creating singleton classes dynamically".

The above specific example might not be a fit use case for my question though.

Comment: Okay, i think the whole idea kinda goes against the benefits of having singleton classes. I dont think your gonna be able to get the instance through an import so your gonna have to manage the instances anyways.